# cannot colour a 3d object in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, 3d

I have made my first 3d image in illustrator, I cannot work out how to colour it. It does not seem to respond to flat colours, not sure if its my pc that is the problem, or something I am not doing. Any help greatly appreiciated, thanks.

It is showing the 3d object just as black lines, outline only.

This is the drawing, as you can see colours for fill and stroke are selected, but they are not displaying. Thank you for helping so far. I tried control Y, but that hasnt helped.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Are you using Illustrator's 3D effects, or did you draw the object yourself? Could you perhaps share a screenshot showing the problem,  and how it was constructed?  It's hard to answer questions like this with so little information. If you are using the 3D effects, it sounds like you have wireframe rendering switched on, but this is only a guess.

Comment: Hi, I drew a triangle, then used 3d effects to make it 3d, using the newer effects,. It was originally coloured but on making it 3d it lost all of its colour

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have wireframe rendering on. Open up your 3D and Materials panel, in the little dropdown at the top right of the panel, switch off Wireframe, and hit Render

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, that works perfectly!

Comment: @mark s - If you feel this answer has correctly answered your question, it would greatly help Graphics Exchange's stats if you would select it as an accepted answer at this point - thanks!